# SQL Developer File Open & Export very slow to display dialog box

Tags: performance, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer, all directory interaction takes 40 seconds to a minute:

- File | Open takes over a minute to display the dialog box
- Export from the results grid takes 40 seconds to display the dialog box, and then another 40 seconds in Export Wizard when clicking the Browse... button next to File:

File I/O speed is very fast, for example exporting the records, or saving query files.

This has been consistently now for several months, and all other applications are immediate to the same file locations.

Comment: We have a fix hopefully for 20.2 due in a few weeks, stay tuned

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, and mentioning the fix will be in 20.2. I am using version 18.2.0.183.1748, and **Check for Updates...** does not find a newer one. I see Oracle.com has 19.4 so I'll try that in the meantime.

Comment: The check for updates you're using is for extensions only, not the base product

Comment: Did this Oracle fix get included in 20.2? I installed release 20.2, and still takes close to a minute for any directory I/O, such as File | Open or Connections | Export.

Answer (score 2):

Update for 2023: finally resolved for me after updating JDK to 11.0.19+7-LTS per advice from @thatjeffsmith

> Java bug, it's fixed - we're going to release that next week. If you can manage to get your hands on Java Java(TM) Platform 11.0.18.0.2 that will make it go away for you, today.— SQL.ProductManager.Oracle.Databases (@thatjeffsmith) [April 14, 2023](https://twitter.com/thatjeffsmith/status/1646879061711486978?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

Previous answer:

Changing setting for Look and Feel from "Oracle" to "Windows" *partially* resolved this for me on SQL Developer 20.4 with Windows 10 and Java 11.

Tools > Preferences > Environment > Look and Feel >  **Windows**

File > Open and File > Save now open immediately.

Query results > Export still takes 40+ seconds; however, the Browse button opens a file chooser immediately.

Update to look and feel is based on tips from @thatjeffsmith :

- [Make SQL Developer Run Faster](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2016/03/make-sql-developer-run-faster)
- [Oracle SQL Developer: Make it Run Faster!](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/02/sql-developer-tastes-great-less-filling/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue persists in my version:

```
Version 22.2.1.234
Build 234.1810
```

Maybe a solution to some: issue caused by network drives (drive letters, regardless if mounted or not, in my understanding), and specific to intentional behaviour of Java 11 (also tested Java 17 Zulu, same issue there). Removing the network drive letters made SQL Developer very responsive.

References:

- [Article on patching JDK](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/for-the-impatient-how-to-patch-the-jdk-and-make-file-open-f-4066)
- [Discussion on the nature of the issue](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/very-long-time-to-open-catalog-in-file-manager-in-22-2-4531)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is working on a fix for this, and hopes to have that included in release 20.2 by end of June 2020.

Comment: This is getting unbearable. Save of open SQL files is 5 seconds. 'Create SQL file takes 4-5 minutes! Let's compare this to a SharePoint save of an Excel or Word doc over the same VPN that is 10-100 times the size and it is 3 seconds.

Comment: Did this Oracle fix get included in 20.2? I installed release 20.2, and still takes close to a minute for any directory I/O, such as File | Open or Connections | Export.

Comment: 20.4, a few more weeks

Comment: Jeff -- problem solved! First, thanks very much for being so directly engaged with your product, very much appreciated.
It seems something in the preferences is causing this slowness: removed the preferences for 20.2 (C:\Documents and Settings\<user-name>\Application Data\SQL Developer\), restarted SQL Developer 20.2, clicked 'No' to import preferences from previous install and viola! 2 seconds instead of 50 for File | Open, and same good performance to the network drive where all my SQL query files are stored, the first time & again when the app defaults there.
Can send the files if useful.

Comment: Yes, the app stores the directory paths, and those are traversed when those dialogs open...if they are network drives, bad things can happen. 20.4 has an option not to persist those paths

Comment: Three months into the new version and performance is still good, passing the test of time. Thanks!

Comment: This is still happening for me in 20.4 on Windows 10. I don't have the folder location @PaulK referenced. No preferences file found in installation directory or in my AppData\Local\Oracle\sqldeveloper directory